# mediaelement.js MP4-Files in Firefox don't work

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have a problem with the current version of the mediaelement-plugin in wordpress. The video format I'm using is a mp4-file.
In IE, Safari, Chrome it works without problems but in Firefox it shows only the HTML5-Player with a "X" in the middle. I found out that mp4-files don't work in firefox, so my question is: Is there any possibility to show the flash-plugin in firefox instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is it showing up with a broken flash player or a broken HTML5 video element?  my understanding is that MediaElement.js will attempt to fallback to Flash on Firefox if you are using an mp4 file.  If you're only using an mp4 file and Flash isn't working, this could explain what you're seeing.

You could either try adding another format (WebM or Ogg on the latest FireFox) or check to see if Flash is working.  In general, you should be including MP4, WebM, and Ogg (in that order) to ensure compatibility across the most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `this.videoRegExp.test(a)?"video":"audio"` returns an incorrect value in 50% of calls. It causes flash palyback loading problem. `/(mp4|m4v|ogg|ogv|webm|flv|wmv|mpeg)/gi.test(a)?"video":"audio"` fixes that issue.

Answer (score 0):

cant work - I suggest you read this: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html
It explain in detail what browser can display what codec

for Firefox and Opera you need Theora+Vorbis+Ogg - though with the newest versions of these browsers webm is working as well. basically you will always need mp4 + ogv + webm to make your videos work on all plattforms. more on that can be found in the article I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how the wordpress plugin works but it should have a flash fallback if the video isn't supported by the browser for html5. i haven't had any problems with the flash fallback for firefox with mp4 files.

Comment: I tried it but the plugin showed me a "X" in the middle of the videoelement which means that the video does not work.